# Issue in linq to entity framework

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

```
(from dtContract in dataEntity.contracts
   where
       (
           dtContract.Supplier_ID == suppID &&
           dtContract.Contract_Year != null
       )
   orderby dtContract.Contract_Year
   select new
       {
           year = (int) dtContract.Contract_Year
       }).ToList();
```

Above LINQ query is converted to following SQL query

```
SELECT 
    `Project1`.`Supplier_ID`, `Project1`.`C1`
FROM
    `contracts` AS `Project1`
WHERE
    (`Project1`.`Supplier_ID` = @p__linq__0)
        AND (`Project1`.`Contract_Year` IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY `Project1`.`Contract_Year` ASC;
```

Which is throwing exception

> Unknown column C1

Can you please provide the reason behind this..?

Comment: dear its the problem from mapping entity to the table

Comment: I am using dbfirst approach.So the model is generated automatically.
Can you please explain what could be the problem in mapping here..?

Comment: Have you updated your edmx-diagram to refresh the class? Can you supply the table columns and the generated class content?

Comment: My model is updated with the latest database and if I remove the order by line from the LINQ query then it is working fine.

Comment: I've seen bugs like this before in SqlConnector. By the way, I happen to know this is MySql but it would be relevant to add the tag to the question.

Comment: Imho, it seems you don't give us all the query generated, ususally EF use parameter and you have a `'Project1'.'Supplier_ID' = 585` in your sample. I expectd to see something like `'Project1'.'Supplier_ID' = @p1`

Comment: @tschmit007, There was a parameter, I updated it manually to 585.when executing sql query on mysql workbench.Now i updated my question again